# What are the options for client-side SOAP+JMS in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, jms

If I'm writing an application in Rails and/or Sinatra, what are my best options if I need to make a number of calls to a SOAP service over JMS?

Can and should I use Savon and ActiveMessaging?  Are there other options that might be better?